# How to get the out parameter from C function in go?

Tags: arrays, string, go, char, cgo

**I have a C function as below:**

`void sign(const char *in, int in_size, char *out, int *out_size);`

**How do I use it in Go?**

**Am I correct?**

```
data:="123456"
cData := C.CString(data)
defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cData))

var _skcy [30]C.char
var outLen C.int
C.sign(cData, C.int(len(data)), &_skcy[0], &outLen)

skcy := C.GoStringN(&_skcy[0], outLen-1)
```

Comment: It looks correct at first glance, are you having a problem with this code?

Comment: it works good, but I'm not sure if it's the right way

Comment: It looks OK, but we don't know what `sign` is or what it does. There's no error checking here, and how you do that depends on the api of `sign`.